# Cant access deployed contract with web3 after restarting local server

Tags: ethereum, solidity, smartcontracts, web3js

I made an app that interacts with a smart contract in the local ganache-cli server, with everything working fine, after restarting the server (and deploying againg the contracts) the app seems to not find the contracts. This is the error that I receive:

> Error: UserController has not been deployed to detected network (network/artifact mismatch)

I've deployed the contracts and restarted the server multiple times but nothing seems to works, also MetaStack is able to interact with the server.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the `--reset --all` flags which tends to resolve this issue.